md:flex-row-reverse not working as expected
I'm trying to work with responsive and dynamic content. I have a variable that allow me to switch the order of my flex container. This is adding flex-row-reverse instead of flex-row. I noticed it didn't work as expected so I tried to write it in a static way but it's still not working.
Here is my original code :
<div class="container flex flex-col md:flex-row-reverse gap-32 justify-between items-center my-80">
    <div class="basis-1/2">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT886zGcOg7rfEglQ-E75tevWWI8boVfdzQC0H163AdYQ&s" alt="alt" class="rounded w-full" />
    </div>
    <div class="content basis-5/12">
        <p class="mb-16">
            Content
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

The md:flex-row-reverse isn't working for me, and the result is just the flex-col.
This code is definitely working on a tailwind playground, but not on my website, I'm not able to debug and understand why.
When I'm checking the output css file, the class exists:
  .md\:flex-row-reverse {
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
  }
...


I also tried directly :
<div class="container flex flex-row-reverse gap-32 justify-between items-center my-80">

It's still not working, however flex-col-reverse is working :
<div class="container flex flex-col-reverse gap-32 justify-between items-center my-80">

the column-reverse in the md also doesn't work:
<div class="container flex flex-col md:flex-col-reverse gap-32 justify-between items-center my-80">

I have honestly no idea how to debug this.

It's weird. It works in https://play.tailwindcss.com/ so this makes me think that there's something breaking your CSS code or something is wrong with your Tailwind.css setup.

I guess yes, but I don't know how I can debug this. Also, the css class exists so I don't see any other reason.

Maybe you can try setting up a separate clean project with Tailwind.css and see if it works or still behaves the same.

I had to re-install the project on my new computer, and it is working. It was probably a bug, we'll never know the cause :)

Actually your code is working fine for me. If I use md:flex-row instead of md:flex-row-reverse I see the result.
